# Maya Python: How to calculate the Reflection Angle/Vector of an given face to camera?

Tags: python, maya

i'm trying to calculate the (averaged) reflection angle of a selection of poly faces in relation to the pov. It's difficult to describe...
I want to place the camera, then i want so select some faces on an object. Next i get a line or something that represents the reflection ray. By lining up a light on that ray i get the reflection of thelight exactly on the poly faces i selected earlier.
Hope it is understandable.

thanks in advance

BTW: I found a mel script that is exactly doing what i am looking for.

http://forums.cgsociety.org/showpost.php?p=7524771&postcount=5

But i could not convert it to python because i have no idea of vectors. Started python just some week ago...

Comment: As @Ale_32 said, you can `eval()` all the mel code but imo I find that quite dirty. You can also convert, line by line the mel code you provided. Some of the functions in this code are only available in mel, so I'd recommand you to use the `numpy` library when working with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

you can get vectors in pymel:

```
from pymel.core.datatypes import Vector
test = Vector(1.0,0.0,0.0)
test2= Vector(0.0,1.0,0.0)
test.dot(test2)
# Result: 0.0
test.cross(test2)
# Result: dt.Vector([0.0, 0.0, 1.0]) #
```

Generically the reflection looks like this:

```
ray = Vector(-2, -3, 1)
nrm = Vector(0,1, 0).normal()

reflection = ray - (2 * (ray.dot(nrm))* nrm)
print reflection
# [-2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
```

where `ray` is the ray from the eyepoint to the surface and `nrm` is the (normalized) surface normal at the intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert it in Python, you can do

```
import maya.mel as mel

# put your MEL code in a string
s = ''
mel.eval(s)
```